# Which FHIR resource to store a patients critical limits for medical measurements?

Tags: hl7-fhir

I'd like to make an application which fetches Observations as they're entered onto the server, compares with pre-stored critical limits for this particular patient and then tags the Observation resource with 'green', 'yellow' or 'red', depending on the values.

What's the best resource to store a patient's limit-values for different types of Observations, deciding which tag to use? Blood pressure, pulse-oximeter, weight etc. I'd like this to be set 'per patient' rather than a system setting. Should I just use a special 'Observation'-resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to set targets on a per-patient basis, that sounds like "goal", though you'll need to distinguish the type of goal somehow in a safe way.  If red means "this is *not* what I want to happen", that might require a modifier extension on Goal, though with the right vocabulary, you could also convey "keep systolic blood pressure above x" as an "affirmative" goal.

Comment: I'm still struggling with this. Goal doesn't give me a place to put the coded values for max/min and possibly different levels and severity, just text. Could have used ReferenceRange of an Observation and made it specific for a patient and with no actual value in the observation (just referencerange), but ReferenceRange is meant to be for a whole population, right, not a specific patient...?

Comment: It seems there's an example of using Goal this way in https://www.hl7.org/fhir/careplan-example.json.html